# Find flattened indices of symmetric elements of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an 5 x 5 numpy array:

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
```

If `a` is flattened:

```
 b = a.flatten()
>> [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24]
```

I am trying to find the indices of symmetry of `b` for `a` where 'symmetry' is defined with respect to `a` shown below:

```
a = np.array([
             [a, d, c, d, a],
             [b, e, f, e, b],
             [c, f, g, f, c],
             [b, e, f, e, b],
             [a, d, c, d, a]
             ])
```

where the elements are 'symmetric' in a square pattern about `g`. The elements shown in the array above are merely placeholders to show the corresponding indices/locations that should be returned.

So, for a given *n* x *m* array the function with return all of the corresponding indices like so:

```
[ 0  4 20 24]
[ 1  3 21 23]
[ 2 10 14 22]
[ 5  9 15 19]
[ 6  8 16 18]
[ 7 11 13 17]
[12]
```

where the output above corresponds to the 'symmetry' like so:

```
[a a a a]
[d d d d]
[c c c c ]
... etc
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Haha I tried posting sample code before and was told it was too confusing so I since removed it and reposted my question for a fresh start. I would be happy to post what I have so far but like I said, I was told it was detrimental to the clarity of my question.

Comment: @SterlingButters it looks like you hit an unfortunate balance in both cases then :( I'm not able to see deleted questions but perhaps your first was way too much code. I can't see a decent attempt at this being more than 10 lines, even if completely broken. How long was the code in your first attempt?

Comment: @roganjosh I know... And the haters are everywhere... My first attempt was ~25 lines of code but it has a major flaw unless there is a trick in initializing a special type of array

Comment: @roganjosh If I can initialize an array that looks like the one with the letters in my question, then I can figure it out.

Comment: Hello (again). This problem will live forever until you re-formulate it clearly. I have a couple of questions: 1) what should be the result for value `d` if `d==c` (i.e., what should be the returned indices); 2) what should be the returned indices for values `c` and `g` when horizontal `c` (on third row) are replaced with `g`?

Comment: @AGN Gazer 1) The indices that should be returned for value `d` are `[1, 3, 21, 23]`. The indices that should be returned for value `c` are `[2, 10, 14, 22]`. It does not matter if value `d` `==c`, the indices that are returned are independent of the elements of the array thus by making `d==c` the problem is less clear because you cannot see how I have defined the symmetry. Each letter that is provided shows what indices should be returned for the entire array. That is, the function should return a list of related/symmetric indices. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: THE VALUES DO NOT MATTER, that is why I used letters this time

Comment: I'm getting closer to a solution by creating an array of arbitrary size and elements and mapping the array based on the elements. (Ignore this if it is not understood)

Comment: @SterlingButters I think that is the key: _"the problem is less clear because you cannot see how I have defined the symmetry"_. Why not define this in a clear mathematical way? The problem will be half-solved only by having a clear formulation.

Comment: I'm saying it is clear right now as it stands. Ok, let's imagine that you can somehow have an empty matrix (no elements or values contained) but somehow it is still an _n_ x _m_ (lets use 5 x 5 as above) array. The purpose of this is to IGNORE the elements. If you were to fold the array in half (from left to right), the first index at (row=0, column=0) would be directly atop of (row=0, column=4). If you were to fold the array in half again, the two previously mentioned indices would be atop of (row=4, column=0) and (row=4, column=4).

Comment: Since those indices are symmetric (because you can fold the array as I described), they correspond. And if you were to flatten the array, (row=0, column=0) becomes `0`, (row=0, column=4) becomes `4`, (row=4, column=0) becomes `20`, and (row=4, column=4) becomes `24`

Comment: So hopefully you can see now that the values DO NOT matter and that purpose of filling the array with elements as I did, was for illustration of the 4-way/square symmetry about (row=2, column=2) (which is where `g` resides).

Comment: I would like to return all corresponding indices of 'symmetry' about the center of the array at (row=2, column=2) (or `g`)

Comment: @ AGN Gazer I would express this mathematically if I could figure it out (Hence the post) and I agree the problem would probably not only be half done but finished. Problem is, it changes with the size of the array (the way I am doing it) and I cannot apply anything, in general, that I have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot for square matrices. It will not be too hard to generalize the algorithm to non-square matrices if you know how the symmetry is defined for those cases.

First, create a 2D array of flattened indices:

```
ind = np.arange(a.size).reshape(a.shape)
mid = a.shape[0] // 2
odd = a.shape[0] % 2
```

Now create a 3D array of the above array flipped along vertical and horizontal axes stacked along 3rd axis:

```
idx = np.dstack([ind, np.fliplr(ind), np.flipud(ind), np.flipud(np.fliplr(ind))])
idx = idx[:mid, :mid].reshape((-1, 4)).tolist()
```

Now, **only if** the size of the array is odd, find the elements sitting/located on middle row and column:

```
if odd:
    idx += np.dstack([ind[:mid, mid], ind[-1:mid:-1, mid],
                      ind[mid, :mid], ind[mid, -1:mid:-1]]).reshape(-1, 4).tolist()
    idx += [[ind[mid, mid]]]
```

Finally, if you want the result sorted at least within a set of indices:

```
idx = sorted(map(sorted, idx))
```

Then, for a `5x5` array one gets:

```
>>> print(idx)
[[0, 4, 20, 24],
 [1, 3, 21, 23],
 [2, 10, 14, 22],
 [5, 9, 15, 19],
 [6, 8, 16, 18],
 [7, 11, 13, 17],
 [12]]
```

Comment: YES!! YOU GOT IT!! Thank you so much. What should I change in my question to make it easier to understand?

Comment: No way would I have figured all that out

Comment: @SterlingButters You are welcome. I just changed the title a bit but also the question needs some clarification. Unfortunately I do not have time right now to do this. I think the main point that needs highlighting is that you are interested only in "locations" (indices) of symmetric points (with regard to reflexions for off-axis points and rotations for on-axis points) in the array.

Answer (score 0):

A hint to help you go forward, is that your problem is recursive. If you know how to find the indices for your *outer* square, you can apply it to the smaller square.

If you can find the 2d coordinates [x,y] and the matrix is n*n, the 1D equivalent is x * n + y

Another hint, it is only working if your matrix is n*n and n is odd. Try to start from the center, and how the indices will looks like around it, then around them etc...

Comment: It is easier to start from a 1x1 matrix, then understand the 3x3, then 5x5 etc... until you see a pattern.